# Cannot find module '../Theme/Icons/' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, react-typescript, react-tsx

I have a new project in React-typescript, where I'm given a repo. The folder structure is as follows:

```
parentDirectory
└───src   
│    │   Components
│    │   Store
│    │   Theme
|         │   Icons
│         │   Styles
```

I have some `svg` and `png` icons in the Icons folder. I'm trying to import them into files inside the `Components` folder, but I'm getting the error:

```html
Cannot find module '../Theme/Icons/' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

My import statement is as follows. I'm not really sure if this is the correct way to do it either:

```
import  { svgComponent as Icon } from '../Theme/Icons/filename.svg'
```

tsconfig.json is as below:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "validationApp"]
}
```

When I use the import

```
import  Icon from '../Theme/Icons/filename.svg'
```

I get the following error:

```html
(commonjs plugin) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\my-app\src\Theme\Icons\filename.svg'
```

I'm used to storing images in the `public` folder at the root and then importing. This file structure is new to me and I'm not allowed to change it. I will edit the question and post anything else if needed. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to do it like: `import  { default as Icon } from '../Theme/Icons/filename.svg'`

Comment: @RyanLe does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using CreateReactApp and don't have access to update your webpack.config, this is probably your best bet.

In your `.d.ts` file add this:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

If you don't have a `.d.ts` file already setup you can create a new one e.g. `custom.d.ts` in your `src` directory.

Then in your tsconfig.json just make sure you have this option set: `"include": [""src/custom.d.ts"]`

Comment: No I don't have access to webpack config. I just re-checked the repo and saw that it has a typings.d.ts file. which has the declaration 
`declare module '*.svg' {
  const svgUrl: string;
  const svgComponent: SvgrComponent;
  export default svgUrl;
  export { svgComponent as ReactComponent }
}` 
and "include": ["src/typings.d.ts"] is not solving the problem